# Having trouble with an asp.net website. updatepanel or div area is not centered when browsing in firefox, but working fine in other browsers

Tags: asp.net, html, updatepanel

I have a website project which is written in asp.net(vb). While I am browsing the website with IE or Chrome it's working fine, but while trying with Firefox it's having some issue. The main div area(or the update panel, not sure) is not showing in the center or in proper position. It's showing in far right and in a scattered way. The div is under an asp updatepanel. Please help with suggestions.

Here is the partial code:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>`enter code here`
h4
{
    padding:3px;
}
table td
{
    padding:3px;
    white-space:nowrap
}

#tblResults td
{
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding:2px;
    text-align:right;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:11px
}

input
{
    font-size:12px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.8.1.js") %>' ></script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<div class="wrapper bot" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding: 0;">
  <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC; ">
        <table width="100%" align="center">
        <tr>
        <td valign="bottom">
        <h2 >ZFlex Calculator</h2>
        </td>
        <td valign="bottom" align="right" style="padding-bottom:7px">
        <asp:LinkButton runat='server' Text="Calculate" ID="btnRecalculate" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="button" />
        <asp:LinkButton runat='server' Text="Print" ID="lnkPrint" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="button" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
     <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat='server' DisplayMode="BulletList"  style="margin-top:5px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #DDDDDD;color:red" />
         <div style="padding:5px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;border: 1px solid #CCCCCC">
        <table align="center">
<tr>
    <td >Wall Type:</td>
    <td >
        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblWallType" RepeatDirection=Horizontal>
         <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected=True>Single Wall</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Double Wall</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td >Category:</td>
    <td >
        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblCategory" RepeatDirection=Horizontal >
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" style="padding:3px" selected="True">Category 1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" style="padding:3px">Category 2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3" style="padding:3px">Category 3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4" style="padding:3px">Category 4</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Fuel Type:</td>
<td >
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblFuelType"  RepeatDirection=Horizontal>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected>Gas</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">LP</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">#2 Fuel Oil</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stack Type:</td>
<td>
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblExhaustType" RepeatDirection=Horizontal>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected>Exhaust Only</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Exhaust and Combustion</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
   </div>
<div style="margin-bottom:15px">
    <h4>Project Information</h4>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Project Name:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="Pnametxt" runat="server" /></td>
            <td>Project For:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="PForTxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td>Company:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="PCompanyTxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Project Location City:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="PCitytxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td>Project Location State:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="PStateTxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<asp:TabContainer ID="tbcTheaterTabs" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" Width="100%" style="margin-top:5px" cssclass="myTabs" EnableViewState="true"    >
<asp:TabPanel ID="tabInputs" runat="server"  HeaderText="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;System Inputs&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" >
<ContentTemplate>

<h4>Appliance Information</h4>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Maximum Input (MBH):</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="MaxInputTxt" runat="server" Width="70px" ValidationGroup="BInputsVal">1000</asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="MaxInputTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    MaximumValue="100000000" MinimumValue="10" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="MaxInputTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
            <td>CO2% in Flue Gas:</td>
            <td colspan="7">
                <asp:TextBox ID="CO2Txt" runat="server" Width="70px" 
                    ValidationGroup="BInputsVal">8.0</asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator5" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="CO2Txt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" MaximumValue="15" 
                    MinimumValue=".5" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="CO2Txt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Minimum Input (MBH):</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="MinInputTxt" runat="server" Width="70px" 
                    ValidationGroup="BInputsVal">500</asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="MinInputTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    MaximumValue="100000000" MinimumValue="0" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="MinInputTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
            <td>Ambient Temp. (F):</td>
            <td colspan="7">
                <asp:TextBox ID="AmbientTempTxt" runat="server" Width="70px" 
                    ValidationGroup="BInputsVal">70</asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator6" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="AmbientTempTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    MaximumValue="200" MinimumValue="-100" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="AmbientTempTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Maximum Gross Temp (F):</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="MaxTempTxt" runat="server" Width="70px" 
                    ValidationGroup="BInputsVal">300</asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator3" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="MaxTempTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    MaximumValue="1400" MinimumValue="100" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="MaxTempTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
            <td>Altitude (Ft.):</td>
            <td colspan="7">
                <asp:TextBox ID="AltitudeTxt" runat="server" Width="70px" 
                    ValidationGroup="BInputsVal">500</asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator7" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="AltitudeTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    MaximumValue="30000" MinimumValue="0" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="AltitudeTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Minimum Gross Temp.(F):</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="MinTempTxt" runat="server" Width="70px" 
                    ValidationGroup="BInputsVal">200</asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator4" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="MinTempTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    MaximumValue="1400" MinimumValue="70" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="MinTempTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
            <td class="style6">
                Exhaust Allowable Pressure Range:</td>
            <td class="style2" colspan="2" width="50">
                Max.</td>
            <td colspan="2" width="150">
                <asp:TextBox ID="MaxPressureTxt" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" 
                    ValidationGroup="BInputsVal">.25</asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator8" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="MaxPressureTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    MaximumValue="10.0" MinimumValue="-2.0" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="MaxPressureTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" width="50">Min.</td>
            <td width="150">
                <asp:TextBox ID="MinPressureTxt" runat="server" ValidationGroup="BInputsVal">-.25</asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator9" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="MinPressureTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    MaximumValue="2" MinimumValue="-2" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="MinPressureTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    <hr />
    <asp:Panel ID="Combustion" runat="server">

    <h4>Combustion Duct Information</h4>

    <table >
    <tr>
        <td>Total Duct Length:</td>
        <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CADuctLengthTxt" runat="server">20</asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator10" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="CADuctLengthTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        MaximumValue="10000" MinimumValue="0" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="CADuctLengthTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">15 Degree Elbow:</td>
                <td class="style78" colspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CA15ElTxt" runat="server">0</asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator18" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="CA15ElTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        MaximumValue="10" MinimumValue="0" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator21" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="CA15ElTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>WYE Tee:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CAWyeTeeTxt" runat="server">0</asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator11" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="CAWyeTeeTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        MaximumValue="10" MinimumValue="0" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator14" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="CAWyeTeeTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td class="style23" colspan="2">
                    30 Degree Elbow:</td>
                <td class="style78" colspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CA30ElTxt" runat="server">0</asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator19" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="CA30ElTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        MaximumValue="10" MinimumValue="0" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator22" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="CA30ElTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style20">
                    90 Degree Tee:</td>
                <td class="style24">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CA90TeeTxt" runat="server">0</asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator12" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="CA90TeeTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        MaximumValue="10" MinimumValue="0" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator15" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="CA90TeeTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td class="style23" colspan="2">
                    45 Degree Elbow:</td>
                <td class="style78" colspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CA45ElTxt" runat="server">0</asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator20" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="CA45ElTxt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        MaximumValue="10" MinimumValue="0" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You have no closing tags for the Combustion Duct Information table and final row. Can you mock this up in jsfiddle and supply a link?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably use margin: 0 auto; to center objects if they are not a direct child of the body element. If the div is a direct child of the body element and the body element is set to width: 100%, the only important remaining aspect is to set a fixed width to the container you wish to center, in your case: div.wrapper

If you have a link, I can narrow down the answer for you, but those are generally good rules to live by. If you are working within an element that is not 100% width of the page, the simple workaround is to use a mathmatic margin calculation. for instance, if the container div is 800px wide, and the div you want to center is 500px, the you would simply set the div you want to center to margin-left: 150px; (800 - 500) / 2.

Comment: This would not center the wrapper area when the browser size is changed.

Comment: It absolutely would if the body is 100% width, container is width: 800px margin: 0 auto, and whatever is inside of it is centered within.

Comment: Then you need to make your second paragraph more explicit ;-)

Comment: But things working fine in chrome or explorer, only showing problem in firefox!!!

Comment: is there any way in stackoverflow so that I can message you the link? @Lawrence

Comment: you can email it to me at lawrence@dub3solutions.com

Comment: Lawrence, what was unclear in the second paragraph was that the body width was set to 100% :-)